# JSF Как влиять на выбор элемента в DataTable после ajax update

Tags: java, ajax, update, jsf, primefaces

Ребят, подскажите, как влиять на выбор элемента в записях из dataTable. Таблица заполнена элементами в первых колонках кнопки редактирования и удаления, дальше поля
 [image: кнопки до нажатия]
 после того, как нажата кнопка удаления, элемент удаляется из DS, таблица обновляется и кнопка удаления первого элемента из оставшихся становиться выбранной и подсвечивается.
[image: после удаления]

Кто подскажет как влиять на это, к примеру я не хочу вовсе выбирать какой ни будь элемент или хочу выбрать кнопку не в первой строке а в произвольной?
вот код кнопки если это поможет

```
<p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
<p:commandButton id="deleteItemBtnTree"
                 icon="ui-icon-close"
                 title="Удалить запись"
                 actionListener="#{commonDimensionItemList.deleteItem(node)}"
                 update="@([id$=commonDimensionItemPanel]), @([id$=treeTableId])"
                 onstart="PF('commonDimensionItemPanelBlock').show()"/>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Что если удалить id у p:commandButton, или обеспечить его уникальность?

Comment: id у кнопки уникален

Answer (score 1):

Решил я эту проблему вот таким способом, вдруг кому поможет в подобной ситуации - единственное, что я нашел пока - `<p:focus for="name"/>` здесь у меня "name" это id элемента `<p:inputText id="name".../>` это элемент, фокус на котором мне более удобен. А для кнопки я добавил process и update для `"@form"` чтобы не терять введенные значения и при этом обновив форму, сместить фокус. Если использовать не actionListner а `f:ajax listener` то в этом случае нужно использовать render и execute для обновления формы.
Если кто, знает альтернативное решение - дайте знать.